# return data from a service

Tags: angular

I have the following code, where I'm generating a menu according to the permissions, I'm consulting the service "this.auth.permissions" that should return me a value, but I can't access it from app.menu, but if I call the observable and give it a console, if it shows me the data, but I don't need the observable but the direct data, to use it inside the function "hasExpectedPermissions"

app.menu.js

```
import { AuthService } from './@auth/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AppMenu implements OnInit{
  permissions:any=[];
  dashboardMenu: NbMenuItem[] = [];


    constructor(private auth: AuthService){
this.auth.permissions$.subscribe(permi=>{
      console.log("permi",permi)
    })
}

  ngOnInit(){

  }

  getMenu(): Observable<NbMenuItem[]> {
    const dashboardMenu = [
      {
        title: 'Dashboard',
        icon: 'home-outline',
        link: '/',
        home: true,
        children: undefined,
      },
      {
        title: 'Users',
        icon: 'person-outline',
        link: '/users',
        data: ['create:user', 'read:user'],
        children: [
          {
            title: 'Users',
            link: '/users',
            data: ['read:user'],
          },
          {
            title: 'Create User',
            link: '/edit-user',
            data: ['create:user'],
          },
        ],

      },
    ];

    function hasExpectedPermissions(page) {
      let permissionsa = this.auth.permissions;

      for(const data of page.data) {
        console.log("data",data);
        page.enabled = permissionsa.indexOf(data) > -1 || page.enabled;
      }

      return page.enabled;
    }

    function getAllowedPages(pages) {
      return pages.filter(function (page) {
        return (page.data === undefined) || (hasExpectedPermissions(page) === true);
      }).map(page => {
        if (page.children) {
          page.children = getAllowedPages(page.children);
        }
        return page;
      });
    }

      console.log('get', getAllowedPages(dashboardMenu) );




    return of([...dashboardMenu]);
  }
}
```

auth.service.js

```
public permissions: string[];
  public permissions$ = new Observable((observer) => {
    this.auth0Client$.subscribe(client => {
      if (client.isAuthenticated()) {
        from(client.getTokenSilently()).subscribe(token => {
          this.tokenSilently$ = token;
          const decodedToken = this.helper.decodeToken(token);
          this.permissions = decodedToken.permissions;
          observer.next(decodedToken.permissions);
        });
      }
    });
  }) as Observable<string[]>;
```

Comment: Where are you making the service call? I'm having trouble understand what the exact problem is - can you please clarify

Comment: inside "hasExpectedPermissions" I'm calling "this.auth.permissions" because there I'm supposed to save the data in this.permissions in the service. @KurtHamilton

Comment: What I mean is, what's calling `permissions$`? If it's not invoked with `.subscribe()`, it won't be run.

Comment: I just edited by calling permissions$ from the builder @KurtHamilton

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting your permissions asynchronously, then you need to build your menu after the service returns the permissions - in the body of the `subscribe`.

Firstly, I have refactored your service to make the chained observable call in a `concatMap` in the pipe rather than using an inner subscribe and an unecessary `Observable` wrapper.

auth.service.ts

```js
permissions$ = this.auth0Client$.pipe(  
  concatMap(client => client.isAuthenticated() ? from(client.getTokenSilently()) : of(null)),
  map(token => {
    if (!token) {
      return [];
    }

    const decodedToken = this.helper.decodeToken(token);
    return decodedToken.permissions;
  })
);
```

Then in your component, you subscribe to that in `ngOnInit` (not the constructor), and build your menu in the `subscribe`. I've not included the building of the menu itself, as this answer is more about showing you the setup of the observables.

app-menu.component.ts

```js
export class AppMenu implements OnInit{
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  permissions = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.auth.permissions$.subscribe(permissions => {
      this.permissions = permissions;

      this.buildMenu();
    });
  }

  private buildMenu(): void {
    // TODO: implement
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what `auth0client` is, but if it's doing anything more complex that a single http request, you will need to look into unsubscribing from the subscription.